# Is there a high level language with an interpreter, dynamic compiler and static compiler(e.g. like the c++ compiler) along with a multimedia library?

Tags: programming-languages, interpreter, dynamic-compilation, high-level, static-compilation

The interpreter and dynamic compiler would be for testing/prototyping and when im done testing i use the static compiler.

Comment: Weird stuff: I think this is exactly what QuickBasic has been touted to be

Answer (score 2):

Java has all of these - the stock Sun JVM has both an interpreter and dynamic compiler, and the GNU Compiler for Java ([GCJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCJ)) can statically compile to machine code.

Answer (score 2):

There are many.

One such language is [Objective Caml](http://caml.inria.fr/).  Let's check it against your requirements:

- [High-level language](http://caml.inria.fr/about/index.en.html): Caml supports functional, object-oriented, and imperative styles of programming.
- [Interpreter](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual023.html): The `ocaml` system is a read-evaluate-print loop.
- [dynamic compiler](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual024.html): On platforms that support dynamic loading, ocamlrun can link dynamically with C shared libraries (DLLs).
- [static compiler](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual025.html): Available through the `-linkall` flag in the compiler.
- Multimedia: There are libraries for [2-d graphics](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=0&browse=44), [3-d graphics](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=0&browse=45), [audio](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=0&browse=46), and [video](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=0&browse=47).

The bigger question is finding the **best** tool for your job.  Many languages meet those requirements, but the most used languages have the best documentation and the most tested bindings to libraries.  If you're going to use a language like Caml, there should be some overriding benefit to that language that can't be found in other languages.

Good luck!

Comment: Many: see http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=0&browse=4 and the links on the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you depends on the kind of your application. If it is a real-time program, then just stay with C++ (or ever with C) because no high-level language like Ruby/Perl/Python will beat them in this domain. But if the complexity of your future program is high enough, the best option I see in **Python** + **PyOpenGL** (for graphics) +**PyOpenAL** (for sound) and **PyODE** (for real-time physics). Actually, Python's VM is fast enough but you can also (with some efforts) compile it into a platform-dependent optimized code.

Alternatively you can use **PyGame** for 2D graphics and a way comfortable sound/music management.